# Git - Magento setup

Tags: git, magento

having this problem that I cannot seem to be able to solve.

SETUP:

1. magento 1.9 (production)
2. exact copy of production on separate IP
3. local magento copy

I've set up 3 separate repos, added 3 remotes for each repo and trying to pull everything through live/master into local but unfortunately I get errors all the time:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD<br>
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I've tried many suggestions on stack overflow and nothing seems to work as xpected.

I'm starting to think that my setup is not correct. 
Please if you could suggest something, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I just need to be able to push and pull from live to dev to local with same unified code and history.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Seems like you did `git init` 3 times on those three repos?

Comment: @Uzbekjon Yes I did, is this something I didnt have to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity: git related issues have much more to do with development than with Magento.

Comment: @MladenIlić - The help centre says that questions need to be "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Is this question "unique to software development"?

Answer (score 0):

By doing `git init` on 3 separate copies of your codebase, you created/initialized 3 separate git repositories that have nothing common. You should have done `git init` on one of the copies and then copy-paste that codebase with hidden `.git` folder to 2 other places. Then, add remotes accordingly.